# Firebase Phone Authentication for new and existing users for web project

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am developing a website which directly sends unregistered and existing user credentials (such as phone number) to firebase server for SMS based phone verification. After the verification is done on the firebase server, my website records the verified phone number in local database. But this way an anonymous user is able to enter multiple phone numbers and generate multiple SMS data charges.
Is there a way to prevent data abuse

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the ip address of the device and limit the number of authentication attempts

Comment: That wont work. Because a fraudster can enter fake phone numbers in the login form and  the firebase will generate SMS OTP leading to data charges in millions. So how to prevent  such fraud with firebase based phone authentication?